# How can we find the fourth derivative of $(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})^n$?

Tags: calculus

How can we find the fourth derivative of $(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})^n$?

This derivative is fine till I get to the second derivative. After which it becomes very difficult to do by the normal method. Is there anyway better way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: This smells like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why are you interested in the 4th derivative of this expression?

Comment: Well, I was assigned this problem.

Comment: Using $\log ( x + \sqrt{x^2 -1}) = \operatorname{arcosh}(x)$ and logarithmic differentiation makes it a little bit easier and more compact.

Comment: Perhaps, you were asked to find the 4th derivative, at a special point e.g. $x=0$? that would be easier

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})^n$$ Cleaning the ["monster"](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B%28x%2BSqrt%5Bx%5E2-1%5D%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D)
$$\frac 1n(x^2 -1)^{\frac 72}\,\frac{f^{(4)}(x)}{f(x)}=$$
$$\left(6 n^2-9\right) x-6 \left(n^2+1\right) x^3+\Big[n \left(n^2+11\right)x^2 -n
   \left(n^2-4\right)\Big] \sqrt{x^2-1}$$

**The trick**

Consider
$$f(x)=\exp\big[n\,t(x)\big]$$
$$f'(x)=f(x) n t'(x)$$ Now, apply the chain rule to finish with
$$f^{(4)}(x)=n e^{n t(x)} \left(n^4 t'(x)^4+6 n^3 t'(x)^2 t''(x)+3 n^2 t''(x)^2+4 n^2 t^{(3)}(x)
   t'(x)+n t^{(4)}(x)\right)$$ and make $t=\cosh ^{-1}(x)$

Answer (score -1):

The result is really long. But I managed to show it. Click on the picture to see it bigger and swipe to view.

[image: table of the derivatives]